# Java Textfield in PopupMenu

Tags: java, popup, awt, spotlight, trayicon

I am trying to add a TextField to a PopupMenu in Java. (similar to Spotlight Feature in Mac OS X)
But i can't add it to as an item because the PopupMenu only accepts MenuItem.

Please help me.

That's the code I currently have:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyTaskTray {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws MalformedURLException {
        final Frame frame = new Frame("");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        // Check the SystemTray is supported
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            return;
        }
        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                new URL("http://home.comcast.net/~supportcd/Icons/Java_Required.jpg")), "Library Drop");
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        // Create a pop-up menu components
        final PopupMenu popup = createPopupMenu();
        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);
        trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    frame.add(popup);
                    popup.show(frame, e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
        }

    }

    protected static PopupMenu createPopupMenu() {
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
        CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
        CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
        Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
        MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
        MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
        MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
        MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        // Add components to pop-up menu
        popup.add(aboutItem);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(cb1);
        popup.add(cb2);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(displayMenu);
        displayMenu.add(errorItem);
        displayMenu.add(warningItem);
        displayMenu.add(infoItem);
        displayMenu.add(noneItem);
        popup.add(exitItem);
        return popup;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding a popmenu in a textfield ;)

Comment: I just found following bug report. There seems to be a workaround, but I can't get it to work in my program. How would you implement it in my program? 
http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6285881